# What is the difference between SBAS and PPP used in GNSS accuracy corrections?

Tags: artificial-satellite, gps, gnss

I've found that Satellite Based Augmentation System uses reference stations to compute a model for correction and send them via a master station to a geosynchronous satellite, then to GPS receiver.

I also found that Precise Point Positioning works the same way, but has a much higher accuracy?

**Why ? does PPP use another correction computational method ?**